# Why do I keep getting back 1011 rather than 1101?

Tags: java, recursion

So, the question is.

What does the recursive code below print when called with number = 13 and base = 2?

```
public static void convert(int number, int base) {

int remainder = number % base;
int quotient = number / base;

if (quotient > 0) convert(quotient, base);
System.out.print(remainder);
```

I've been running through this on paper for about an hour and no matter what i keep coming up with 1011 rather than 1101.

Am I just doing the math wrong or what?

Comment: What is `case`?

Comment: Oh, yes. I missed that it should be base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing the print AFTER the recursive call, you'll print out the remainders in reverse order, e.g. 2^0-bit, 2^1-bit, and so on. Rather than 2^3-bit, 2^2-bit, etc.. Move the print before the if-statement and it should work fine.

Comment: The binary encoding of 13 base 2 is 1101, so the way your program works, is as it should be. 1011 base 2 = 11 base 10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the code should look like

```
public static void convert(int number, int base) {
    int remainder = number % base;
    int quotient = number / base;
    if (quotient > 0) convert(quotient, base);
    System.out.print(remainder);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    convert(13, 2);
}
```

Iterations:

```
A) number = 13, base = 2, remainder = 1, quotient = 6; 
B) number = 6, base = 2, remainder = 0, quotient = 3;
C) number = 3, base = 2, remainder = 1, quotient = 1; 
D) number = 1, base = 2, remainder = 1, quotient = 0; print "1"
c) print "1"
b) print "0"
a) print "1"
```

So it looks like the output should = 1101.